# why keyup event not works on input tags that dynamically added to page?

Tags: jquery

i want to add input tag dynamically add to my page by jquery but when add it "keyup" event not work,but when add input to page by hard code it works.

i look at my codes by firebug every things is OK but i thing when page going to render keyup event assign to all elements that i define by ".txtbox" class and when i add another one dinamically it ha not this event.

how can i handle this problem?

```
var i = 0;//generate a number for id
function addit() {
i = i + 1;

  //this line add dynamic input to a div with class ".x"
 $(".x").prepend('<input id=\'Text1' + i + '\' value=\'' + i+ '\' type=\'text\'
                    class=\'txtbox\'  /><br />');

}

//when page load all ".txtbox" classes get "keyup" event
$(function () 
   {
  $('.txtbox').keyup(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          alert("hi");
        }
    });
});


//html codes
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="add it" onclick="addit()" />

 <div class="x">
        <input id="Text11" value="1" type="text" class="txtbox" /><br />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with event delegation

```
 $('.x').on("keyup",".txtbox",function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {//here you use e.which then it will good
          alert("hi");
        }
    });
```

use **[event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)**

The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.